# group 4 numbers into a 4 digit number in C++

Tags: c++

How to group num1num2num3num4 into a number and prime1prime2prime3prime4 into a number to make sure their combination is not identical??

```
srand(time(NULL));
    int num1 = 2 * (rand() % 5) + 1, num2 = 2 * (rand() % 5) + 1, num3 = 2 * (rand() % 5) + 1, num4 = 2 * (rand() % 5) + 1;//odd number
    int prime1 = 2 * (rand() % 4) + 1, prime2 = 2 * (rand() % 4) + 1, prime3 = 2 * (rand() % 4) + 1, prime4 = 2 * (rand() % 4) + 1;

    if (prime1 == 1)
        prime1 = prime1 + 1;
    else
        prime1 = prime1;
    if (prime2 == 1)
        prime2 = prime2 + 1;
    else
        prime2 = prime2;
    if (prime3 == 1)
        prime3 = prime3 + 1;
    else
        prime3 = prime3;
    if (prime4 == 1)
        prime4 = prime4 + 1;
    else
        prime4 = prime4;
    //output of credit card number
    cout << "Enter last four digits of NRIC no: ";cin >> icno1 >> icno2 >> icno3 >> icno4;
    cout << num1 << num2 << num3 << num4<<" ";//odd number
    cout << prime1 << prime2 << prime3 << prime4 << " ";//prime number
```

Comment: What is the expected output of your program? What is the current output?

Comment: "`else prime1 = prime1;`". self assignation is no-op, so that code is unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for ?

```
int fourDigits1 = num1   + num2   * 10 + num3   * 100 + num4   * 1000;
int fourDigits2 = prime1 + prime2 * 10 + prime3 * 100 + prime4 * 1000;

std::cout << fourDigits1 << " ";
std::cout << fourDigits2 << " ";
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers